# Is there a way to view the source of a web page AFTER all jquery scripts have run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I currently use Chrome/Firefox for my web development.

Is there a plugin, or am I just another way, where you can view the HTML source AFTER all jQuery plug-ins have run? I just want to see what and how jQuery modified the HTML?

Comment: +1 Good question, I hadn't thought of that before.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) will show the state of the DOM as it is in the current point in time:

[image]
<sub>(source: [getfirebug.com](https://getfirebug.com/perch/resources/1261505899html1.gif))</sub>

Comment: @Rex M, What Program have you used to take this printscreen?

Answer (score 18):

There is a much easier way to do this without installing **any** plugins:

**Ctrl-A to select all content on the page, and right-click "view source"**

(only works in firefox of course)

Answer (score 13):

In Firefox:

Use the web developer tool by Chris Pederick.  Go to View Source -> View Generated Source.
Using this same tool, highlight elements you would like to see the generated source for and then right click to see View Selection Source.

Or, you could use the Firebug tool, to inspect the elements on the page.

Comment: +1 for Web Developer.  I find this easier to read the source in than Firebug.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for that (in Firefox, obviously). It actually tracks the page's current DOM, instead of displaying the original source.

Answer (score 4):

Right click and select 'Inspect element'. That will show you the HTML after it has been loaded in Chrome.

For Firefox: Install firebug, then you will see the 'inspect element' option.

Answer (score 2):

firebug for firefox will pick up changes to the DOM.