# See Page Source on a ajax based implementation

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having a set of pages where in I am using JQTouch jquery library. How can I see the page source after an Ajax call. I suppose the DOM gets replaced, but when I see the page source I am not able to see the updated set of contents. This is hampering my debbugging. Does anyone know of some way to see the page source....

Comment: There is a good answer (if I do say so myself :)) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335737/is-there-a-way-to-view-the-source-of-a-web-page-after-all-jquery-scripts-have-run/1335753#1335753

Answer (score 2):

Firebug can show you the source for the current DOM.  However if there are errors in the actual source code used to generate that dom you may get unspecified behaviour, where the page appears to work in one browser and doesn't work at all in another.

Comment: +1, Firebug can tell you the source of the new content loaded.